# Why the font-family and font-size in pre css can't take effect?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

Here is my customized twenty-fourteen css.

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty Fourteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fourteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfourteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fourteen-child
*/

pre{
    font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono !important;
    font-size:16px;
    border:4px solid red;
}
```

The default font-family was set as DejaVu Sans Mono in firefox--preference--content--fonts and colors.

1.Other characters such as sidebar was displayed as font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono.

2.The font-family displayed as `font-family:DejaVu Sans Mono` when to inspect with firebug.

3.`border:4px solid red;` take effect.

[image]

Why the font-family and font-size in pre css can't take effect?
It is no use to write it as `font-family:"DejaVu Sans Mono" !important;`,can't take effect!!

[image]

Comment: Quote names with spaces `font-family:"dejavu sans mono"` else it looks for dejavu, then sans, then mono.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/do4aef3p/ You do actually have that font installed?  Look at the computed tab in dev tools to see the inheritance of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To  fix  `<pre lang="bash">  as <pre>` ,problem solved.
The meaning of    in wordpress plugin--wp syntax was mixed with html standard pre tag,no lang attribution in html standard,it is a private extend attribution in wp syntax.